# Merge Arrays with Overlapping Numerical Keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to figure out how to merge two arrays that use a numerical key. I have two arrays for example:

```
$array1[1] = array('service'=>array(1=>array('name'=>'Emergency','Price'=>10,'start_date'=>'2015-01-01')));
$array2[1] = array('calls'=>array('123456789'=>array('total'=>'150','Price'=>10,'cdrs'=>array(1=>array('src'=>123456789,'dist'=>987654321)))));
```

They both have a key of one as they both belong to customer number 1. I need to end up with a resulting array that appears like so:

```
Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
            [service] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Emergency
                        [Price] => 10
                        [start_date] => 2015-01-01
                    )

            )

            [calls] => Array
            (
                [123456789] => Array
                    (
                        [total] => 150
                        [Price] => 10
                        [cdrs] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [src] => 123456789
                                        [dist] => 987654321
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        )

)
```

This way I can use two methods to return two massive arrays and then simply merge them and loop through.

I have tried both `array_merge` and also the following which I was not aware of:

```
$merged = $array1 + $array2;
```

However, neither method seems to achieve the goal and simply return one or the other. Does anyone have any advice as to how I can achieve this?

Comment: I might be able to answer you, but i am not very familiar with PHP - How would you like to merge them, again? Is it a simple ascending/descending order, or somthing else?

Generally, I'd implement the merging function myself. It should not be extreamly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now but I think this should work.

```
$newArray = [];
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array1);$i++){
    $newArray[] = array_merge($array1[$i],$array2[$i]);
}
return $newArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge two array using function array_merge_recursive as:

```
  $result[1] = array_merge_recursive($array1[1],$array2[1]);
   //You can change key as per your need may be dynamic
    print_r($result);
```